# Is there Way to Cover Surface this Ways not Working Very well { Fill/Grid Fill/Beautify Faces } take match more time to solve

Tags: mesh, scripting, edit-mode

[image][image: want to Fill Around Holes/voids]

My Problem is Fill Around holes and used all ways but not Working as I wish , manual Editing take More time

Comment: Hello, you are trying to go from 2nd picture to 1st picture ?

Comment: Hello ,Its Just for Explain ,I made extrude To lines That imported From AutoCAD Drawing ,I found now Tool  But so slow in 3d view port During Rotation & Movement { remesh  } So magic Tool but So slow and it's not accuracy https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html

Comment: Sorry I think the language barrier is a bit too thick to understand here... Could you add a screenshot or diagram with what you are trying to do, if only on a small area ?